# error Attempted import error: 'NotificationsNoneIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/icons'

Tags: reactjs

i have a question , why i recieve this error while compiling :
Attempted import error: 'NotificationsNoneIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/icons'.

because i installed material icon and there is my code :
could you help me ?

```
import React from 'react';
import   './topbar.css'
import {NotificationsNoneIcon,Language,Settings} from '@material-ui/icons';
function Topbar() {
    return (
        <div className="topbar">
            <div className="topbarWrapper">
                <div className="topleft">
                    <span className="logo">lammadamin</span>
                </div>
                <div className="topright">
                    <div className="topbarIconContainer">
                        <NotificationsNoneIcon/>
                        <span className="topIconBadge">2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="topbarIconContainer">
                        <Language/>
                        <span className="topIconBadge">2</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="topbarIconContainer">
                        <Settings/>
                        <span className="topIconBadge">2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Topbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accords https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/,

You should import without `Icon` word

```
import {NotificationsNone as NotificationsNoneIcon,Language,Settings} from '@material-ui/icons';
```